# Определение имени человека

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymorphy2

Есть текст. Нужно в этом тексте найти имена. Перебрать каждое слово и как-то определить: имя человека это или что то левое. Помогите с решением. Возможно есть какие то библиотеки? Заранее спасибо. Язык - русский, украинский.

**Update:**

Пример текста:

> Привет вам от Светланы. Привіт усім, Микола з Київа. А я из Мюнхена,
>   звать меня Макс. Андрея не забудьте. Наталію також! Надія. Даниіл.
>   Вітання від Даниіла.

Из этого текста нужно вытянуть имена людей.

Comment: А язык имён известен?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman дописал) рус и укр

Comment: Наверное, потребуется готовая база имён... да и с ней могут быть накладочки, потому как попадётся кто-нить вроде Розмари или там Низами - и гадай, имя это или фамилия...

Comment: Можно попробовать поискать слова с большой буквы не в начале предложения.

Comment: @Akina пусть будет и фамилия, главное узнать из текста как можно к человеку обратится. Можно и по фамилии назвать. Но я точно знаю что в тексте точно будут имена, фамилий не будет.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman текст может быть и таким - "0989189960. Светлана"

Comment: Ну в общем большой проблемы не вижу. Ищем таблицу имён (вряд ли большая проблема), находим несколько, сливаем в одну, и загоняем в БД. Потом получаем текст, чистим его от пунктуации, делим на слова, сливаем в таблицу в той же БД и одним запросом получаем список встретившихся в тексте абы имён. А если ещё надо и место - ну в процессе деления на слова для каждого слова запоминаем оффсет в исходном тексте.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman А если имя в начале предложения? Почему надо *"не в начале предложения"*?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov это была идея как искать имя без использования словаря имен. В середине предложения слово с большой буквы - имя собственное. Если имя стоит в начале предложения, то его нельзя определить без словаря.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Да всё равно порочная идея. Потому что имя собственное — это не обязательно имя человека. Это может быть страна, река и т.д. А вопрос про *имя человека*. Был бы это ответ — с радостью бы минусанул.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov поэтому и не ответ.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Шаг лемматизации куда выкинули? ["Андрей"](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=12977) найдётся, а "Андрея" не найдёте. Велосипеды изобретаете.

Comment: @AK про словарь предложил не я.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Точно, не заметил. Прошу прощения.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Просто даже в форме комментария — это вредный совет.

Comment: а какова причина переоткрытия?

Answer (score 7):

Вот рабочий пример с использованием [pymorphy2](http://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/guide.html):

```
import nltk
import pymorphy2

# probability score threshold
prob_thresh = 0.4

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

text = """
0989189960. Привет вам от Светланы.
Привіт усім, Микола з Київа.
А я из Мюнхена, звать меня Макс.
Андрея не забудьте.
Наталію також!
Надія.
Даниіл. Вітання від Даниіла.
"""

for word in nltk.word_tokenize(text):
    for p in morph.parse(word):
        if 'Name' in p.tag and p.score >= prob_thresh:
            print('{:<12}\t({:>12})\tscore:\t{:0.3}'.format(word, p.normal_form, p.score))
```

Результат:

```
Светланы        (    светлана)  score:  0.75
Микола          (      микола)  score:  1.0
Макс            (        макс)  score:  0.833
Андрея          (      андрей)  score:  0.652
```

**UPDATE:**

> А с именем "Даниіл" прокатит?

```
In [90]: word
Out[90]: 'Даниіл'

In [91]: parsed = morph.parse(word)

In [92]: parsed
Out[92]:
[Parse(word='даниіл', tag=OpencorporaTag('VERB,impf,tran masc,sing,past,indc'), normal_form='даниіть', score=0.7622198826891251, methods_sta
ck=((<FakeDictionary>, 'даниіл', 206, 7), (<KnownSuffixAnalyzer>, 'л'))),
 Parse(word='даниіл', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,nomn'), normal_form='даниіл', score=0.10076703263648654, methods_stack=((<Fake
Dictionary>, 'даниіл', 33, 0), (<KnownSuffixAnalyzer>, 'л'))),
 Parse(word='даниіл', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,masc sing,accs'), normal_form='даниіл', score=0.10076703263648654, methods_stack=((<Fake
Dictionary>, 'даниіл', 33, 3), (<KnownSuffixAnalyzer>, 'л'))),
...
```

**Подытожим:** украинские имена распознаются пока не очень хорошо...

Comment: А с именем "Даниіл" прокатит?)

Comment: @SkiesX, не прокатило...

Comment: `'Данило'` - понимает...

Comment: думал как сделать и дошёл к тому что может переводить слово на рус и проверять его. Потому что укр мне нужен, то есть как система вся на укр, и текст будет попадаться в большинстве случаев на укр.

Comment: я бы попробовал разобраться с добавлением имён в укр. словарь - заодно поучавствуете в проекте и поможете будущим пользователям ;) А еще лучше попробовать написать укр. модуль для [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml)

Comment: Было бы интересно) Но сейчас пока времени нету( я это про модуль.

Comment: ЕМНИП Даниил ишется с "и" с двумя точками (которая "йи"). Хотя тоже не факт что в словаре есть.

Comment: @insolor, я попробовал с `'Даниїл'` - результат тот же. Похоже украинский словарь для `pymorphy2` пока не очень дружит с именами

Comment: Украинские и не будут. Автор pymorphy и pymorphy2 опирается на открытый корпус русского языка opencorpora.org - украинских слов очевидно там просто нет. Если знаете подходящие (открытые) лингвистические корпуса и словари для украинского языка -- то просите у автора библиотеки. Если хотите помочь в улучшении корпуса русского языка -- присоединяйтесь к opencorpora.org

Comment: `Данило` этот код понимает потому что это не только украинское, но ещё  и русское имя и оно есть в словаре опенкорпоры: http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=78225

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант сделать это с помощью `pymorphy2`.

Цитата автора `pymorphy2`:

> В OpenCorpora имена отмечены пометкой Name (см.
>   http://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/grammemes.html), т.е.
>   можно написать что-то вроде
>
> ```
> is_name = any('Name' in p.tag for p in morph.parse(word))
> ```
>
> Если какого-то имени нет в OpenCorpora (а это бывает, особенно с
>   уменьшительно-ласкательными вроде "Алёшенька"), можно завести тикет
>   тут: https://github.com/OpenCorpora/opencorpora/issues
>
> В украинском словаре этой пометки нет.
>
> Если бы мне эту задачу надо было решать на практике, я бы в дополнение
>   к pymorphy2 постарался еще найти/скачать откуда-нибудь списки имен.

https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2/issues/83

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста рабочий пример. Я думаю многим было бы интересно